# Restrict s3 file to Django group user

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-storage

My web app uses Amazon S3 to store all the media files in my djagno web app with the help of the django-storages 3rd party app.

My db handle the folder and files hierarchy and each user see just the links that belongs to his group.

But! there is no permissions to the other folders at S3.

for example:
user 1 : group is group1
user 2: group is group2
s3 link: https://s3.amazonaws.com//media/group1/folder1/1.png

user 1 will see this at his page inside the app.
user 2 won't see this link, but if he tried to get to this link, there is no permissions on the file and it will be downloaded easily.

My goal is to restrict folder permission to each group.

There is automatically solution that based on my aws keys?
I'm lost...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit New Solution:**

The Amazon SDK Provides the Pre-Signed Url Feature.
With this you can generate temporary urls to one specific file only for your users.

So the Use case scenario is this.
The S3 Images remain still private.
When a user requests his images, you pass all the links first to the Signing Handler which generates the temp links. (These are set to expire and have plenty of encryption and protection , so it's impossible for someone to hijack such a link).

The end user can load and view the files in his browser directly from amazon like nothing happened.

**Old Solution**

Well another workaround might be to store all files in s3 **without** public access.
Then create an IAM Role for your application and give that role access to the bucket.
Then Create a method which will read the S3 files within your application , and serve them to the user if he has rights.

Simple example.

S3 File Path

//media/group1/folder1/1.png

Request = MyWebMethod/GetFile?internalPath="folder1/1.png"

{

Int userId = customAuthentication.getUserId();

String CompletePath = "media/group"+userId+"/"+internalPath

var image = AwdSdkClient.getFileFromS3(CompletePath);

return image;

}

So by default each user can request files only within his group.

A more advanced way, is not to fetch the file actually to your server , but create some kind of median data stream pipe to the file. (I am not a Django developer so i don't know if this is feasible )

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to effectively provide single sign-on for your web authenticated users.  One way, perhaps the only way to handle this, is through the use of a [SAML provider](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/idp-managing-identityproviders.html).  Doing this, you'll map your third-party authenticated users/groups to [AWS IAM](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/IAM_Introduction.html) users/groups.

It will work, but it will require much more than a few mouse clicks.